# Need to get or populate the checkbox status when clicked on edit

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, checkbox

I've check boxes displayed in the Recycler view with edit and delete options. Now I need to see / populate the data / get the Clicked / checked checkBox when I click on edit.

**My Recycler View Activity**

class RecView : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private var is_Role01: Boolean = false
private var is_Role02: Boolean = false
private var is_Role03: Boolean = false
private var is_Role04: Boolean = false
private var is_Role05: Boolean = false

private lateinit var addsBtn: FloatingActionButton
private lateinit var recv: RecyclerView
private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<UserData>
private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter
private lateinit var RN: EditText
private lateinit var UN: CheckBox
private lateinit var PN: CheckBox
private lateinit var BD: CheckBox
private lateinit var AN: CheckBox
private lateinit var PR: CheckBox

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recview)
    userList = ArrayList()
    addsBtn = findViewById(R.id.addingBtn)
    recv = findViewById(R.id.mRecycler)
    myAdapter = MyAdapter(this, userList)
    recv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recv.adapter = myAdapter
    addsBtn.setOnClickListener { addInfo() }
}


@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
private fun addInfo() {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adduser, null)
    val addDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    RN = v.findViewById(R.id.roleName)
    UN = v.findViewById(R.id.role01)
    PN = v.findViewById(R.id.role02)
    BD = v.findViewById(R.id.role03)
    AN = v.findViewById(R.id.role04)
    PR = v.findViewById(R.id.role05)

    addDialog.setView(v)
    addDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, _ ->
        val rolename = RN.text.toString()
        val names = UN
        val number = PN
        val dob = BD
        val anni = AN
        val per = PR

        userList.add(UserData("Role Name : $rolename", names, number, dob, anni, per))
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Adding User Information Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        dialog.dismiss()

        UN.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            val checked: Boolean = UN.isChecked
            is_Role01 = checked
        }
        PN.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            val checked: Boolean = PN.isChecked
            is_Role02 = checked
        }
        BD.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            val checked: Boolean = BD.isChecked
            is_Role03 = checked
        }
        AN.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            val checked: Boolean = AN.isChecked
            is_Role04 = checked
        }
        PR.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            val checked: Boolean = PR.isChecked
            is_Role05 = checked
        }


    }
    addDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    addDialog.create()
    addDialog.show()
}
```

}

**My Adapter Class**
Where I have edit and delete options.

class MyAdapter(val c: Context, val userList: ArrayList) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

```
inner class UserViewHolder(val v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    var roleName: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.mRoleName)
    var name: CheckBox = v.findViewById(R.id.role01)
    var mbNum: CheckBox = v.findViewById(R.id.role02)
    var dob: CheckBox = v.findViewById(R.id.role03)
    var anni: CheckBox = v.findViewById(R.id.role04)
    var per: CheckBox = v.findViewById(R.id.role05)

    var mMenus: ImageView

    init {
        mMenus = v.findViewById(R.id.mMenus)
        mMenus.setOnClickListener { popupMenus(it) }
    }

    @SuppressLint("DiscouragedPrivateApi", "NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun popupMenus(v: View) {
        val position = userList[adapterPosition]
        val popupMenus = PopupMenu(c, v)
        popupMenus.inflate(R.menu.menu)
        popupMenus.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.editText -> {
                    val v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.adduser, null)
                    val roleName = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.roleName)
                    val name = v.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.role01)
                    val number = v.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.role02)
                    val dob = v.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.role03)
                    val anni = v.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.role04)
                    val per = v.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.role05)
                    AlertDialog.Builder(c).setView(v).setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, _ ->
                        position.roleName = roleName.text.toString()
                        position.userName = name
                        position.userMb = number
                        position.userDob = dob
                        position.userAnni = anni
                        position.per = per
                        notifyDataSetChanged()
                        Toast.makeText(c, "User Information is Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                        dialog.dismiss()

                    }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                        dialog.dismiss()

                    }.create().show()

                    true
                }
                R.id.delete -> {
                    /**set delete*/
                    AlertDialog.Builder(c).setTitle("Delete").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning)
                        .setMessage("Are you sure delete this Information")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, _ ->
                            userList.removeAt(adapterPosition)
                            notifyDataSetChanged()
                            Toast.makeText(c, "Deleted this Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        }.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ ->
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        }.create().show()

                    true
                }
                else -> true
            }

        }
        popupMenus.show()
        val popup = PopupMenu::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
        popup.isAccessible = true
        val menu = popup.get(popupMenus)
        menu.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", Boolean::class.java)
            .invoke(menu, true)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
    return UserViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val newList = userList[position]
    holder.roleName.text = newList.roleName

    if (newList.userName.isChecked) {
        holder.name.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        holder.name.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    if (newList.userMb.isChecked) {
        holder.mbNum.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        holder.mbNum.visibility = View.GONE
    }


    if (newList.userDob.isChecked) {
        holder.dob.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        holder.dob.visibility = View.GONE
    }


    if (newList.userAnni.isChecked) {
        holder.anni.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        holder.anni.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    if (newList.per.isChecked) {
        holder.per.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        holder.per.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}
```

}

**My Data Class**

data class UserData(
var roleName: String,
var userName: CheckBox,
var userMb:CheckBox,
var userDob:CheckBox,
var userAnni:CheckBox,
var per:CheckBox
)

The Data which are given while saving initially should be populated to the edit screen. Could anyone help me out with this.

[In here I've selected 2 check boxes and given a Role Name as Admin, now when I click on menu the same data should be populated or get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr0Af.png)

[When I click on edit, the data selected in the previous page should be visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgkms.png)